# Can fetch Data inside the class but when return it's send only boolean value php PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to build database class using PDO this my first time using pdo so while i am building i am stuck in this problem i was able create and connect to database using class but problem is when i am trying to execute and fetch returned data error says

> Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

and yet i can do this fetching inside the class this problem arise only when i am trying to fetch returned data and i have echoed the returned data it is returning 1

**This is function that's trying to return (did not use parameters just using dummy)**

```
 public function init($query,$param =[]){
        if(!$this->bConnected) { $this->Connect(); }
        try{
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM business');
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->execute();


        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }




     }
```

**Calling to class object name is $myobj**

```
 $stmt = $myobj->init('SELECT * FROM business',$value);

    while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        echo( $rows['bs_name'] ."  |" .$rows['bs_id']. "<br>");
    }
```

**This is same code only difference is this is inside the class.working without any errors**

```
   public function init($query,$param =[]){
        if(!$this->bConnected) { $this->Connect(); }
        try{
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM business');
            $stmt->execute();
             $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo( $rows['bs_name'] ."  |" .$rows['bs_id']. "<br>");
            }

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }




     }
```

Comment: Read the docs for [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).  Specifically the "Return Values" section.

Answer (score 3):

Your method returns the result of `$stmt->execute()` (a boolean indicating success/failure of the statement execution, *not the query results*).

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM business');
return $stmt->execute();
```

Instead, for the method to work the way you're using it, you need to execute the statement and then return the statement itself, not the result of `execute()`.

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM business');
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you thank you very much i just spend 2 hours trying to figure this out

Comment: Nicely explained.

Comment: @ThalindaBandara I know how it goes, sometimes the answer is right there and it seems obvious after you see it. I'm actually just taking a break after spending a few hours trying to solve the wrong problem myself.  Good times ;-)

Comment: Thanks @FunkFortyNiner